# Load Another FXML from a FXML initialize

Tags: java, netbeans, javafx

I want to load another FXML file if status is "1". But in this following code, its not load another FXML from initialize. If I use a button then this code work but I want to do this without any button. Can anyone help me by giving me a suggestion?

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    String status = "1";
    if(status.equals("1")){
        try {
            Parent root = null;
            root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/fxml/anotherFXML.fxml"));
            Scene scene = new Scene(root);
            MainClass.getStage().setScene(scene);
            MainClass.getStage().show();

            System.err.println("Success");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println("Failed");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it's not a good way to load new scene inside `initialize` method and it causes exception.

By the way, you can do it with some seconds delay because you are trying to call `stage.show()` twice in a time(once in your `initialize` method and once in your `Application` class).

For example you can use `PauseTransition`.

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

    PauseTransition delay = new PauseTransition(Duration.seconds(1));
    delay.setOnFinished(event -> {
        //load your view
    });
    delay.play();

}
```